# How to give a permission to the user to enter only number between 1 to 100 using jQuery or javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to restrict the user to enter only number between 1 - 100 suppose if he is entering 101 i should give a popup message says please enter any number between 1 - 100?

Using jquery or javascript

thansk

Comment: I think a popup would be annoying for this.  Instead, why not have a validation message show beside where the user is entering the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($('#element_id').val() > 100 || $('#element_id').val() < 1) { 
    alert( "Please enter a number between 1 - 100 "); 
}
```

Comment: You have some subtle type conversions going on there. What if the user types `0xf`? Or `0x3a`? or `0125`? This code says those are valid, but should they be? I guess that's the OPs call...

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a popup message, but I thought I would show you the other option (expanding on George Cummins' code):

```
$("#element_id").keyup(function() {
    if ($('#element_id').val() > 100 || $('#element_id').val() < 1) {
        $("#validationMessage_id").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#validationMessage_id").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  if (Number($('.target')[0].value) < 0 || Number($('.target')[0].value) > 100) {
    alert('Number must be less than 100');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what Devneck did, except setting the field back to empty if the value is invalid.

```
    $('.target').change(function () {
        if (Number($(this).val()) < 0 || Number($(this).val()) > 100) {
            $(this).val('');
            alert('Number must be less than 100');
        };
    });
```

Comment: that's terrible!  if a user accidentally types an extra number he has to start over instead of just backspace.